# Backup files with backup-manager are empty

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, backup

On my ubuntu server I use from long time backup-manager to dump and backup on FTP all MySQL databases, everything worked like a charm form this time. All of a sudden the backups files are empty. I try to manually dump DB with mysqldump and the dedicated user in the backup-manager conf and it's working. When I launch backup-manager in manual mode there is no error, just empty dumps ...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It's resolved. This is because I had a ~/.my.cnf conf file that override the MySQL user in the backup-manager conf

https://github.com/sukria/Backup-Manager/issues/12#issuecomment-8830271